# Is it possible to determine whether a WM_MOUSEMOVE from mice or touchpad?

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

I need to detect the source of message WM_MOUSEMOVE, but I could not find any resource on the internet.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for a touchpad, because that's just a different type of mouse. For touch screens and tablets though, there's a load of new interaction messages under Win7 and Win8 especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe it is not possible. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` describes move of the mouse cursor on the screen, no matter what device caused the action. Actually it even might be software-emulated move of the mouse cursor, i.e. not caused by any HW device at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually Raw Input could detect where the mouse_move message comes from, otherwise other input device such as joystick etc will not work.

Comment: Yes, using [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543.aspx) will give you this information, but it doesn't work with `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages, which is what the question asked about. As far as `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is concerned, all input devices are created equal. If you need the additional information, you need to process the input at a lower level. Additionally, when using Raw Input, you miss out on certain automatic enhancements that Windows adds when you process the input the normal way, such as pointer acceleration. Users probably expect this for trackpads.